# Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Chrome Audits Pass

Tags: google-pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

When I audit the website on Chrome Devtools, everything runs smoothly, however I started getting this error recently on PageSpeed Insights:

*Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. O Lighthouse não conseguiu carregar com fiabilidade a página que solicitou. Certifique-se de que está a testar o URL correto e que o servidor está a responder adequadamente a todos os pedidos. (Detalhes: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT)*

When test it with Lighthouse Report Viewer Chrome extension, I get same error.
Already tested in Incognito Mode and same error.

**site URL:** https:/ebody.pt

Please any help on this.

Kind regards

Comment: Do you use lighthouse as extension or the built-in one - this built-in works sometimes worse than this from extension. Also in lighthouse description it's recomended to not have any other extensions while running tests.

Comment: Hi Zydnar, thanks for your comment.
I use both. In the beginnig I started to use the lighthouse extension, but when stopped working, I started using the built-in-one.

Comment: You may report this as issue alt + shift + i they fix issues really fast. Also if you're using chrominium, lighthouse is more buggy.

Comment: Runs fine for me, you get 64/100 for mobile. Try it again and if it doesn't work I may have a fix for you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for all the answers.
It worked again without me having done anything !!
Kind regards.